# How to specify default value for Rotation in SLD?

Tags: style, sld, geotools

Am using geotools to render a set of point features. I have SLD for styling point features. The SLD uses an expression to calculate Rotation value based on *Angle* attribute value of feature. The features that have *Angle* value NULL are not rendered. I would like to specify default angle value of 0 when *Angle* attribute value is NULL.

Here is part of current SLD:

```
<sld:Rule>
<sld:Name>rule1</sld:Name>
<sld:PointSymbolizer>
<sld:Graphic>
<sld:ExternalGraphic>
<sld:OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="mysymbol.svg" xlink:type="simple"/>
<sld:Format>image/svg</sld:Format>
</sld:ExternalGraphic>
<sld:Opacity>
<ogc:Literal>1.0</ogc:Literal>
</sld:Opacity>
<sld:Size>
<ogc:Literal>11.0</ogc:Literal>
</sld:Size>
<sld:Rotation>
<ogc:Sub>
<ogc:Literal>360.0</ogc:Literal>
<ogc:PropertyName>Angle</ogc:PropertyName>
</ogc:Sub>
</sld:Rotation>
</sld:Graphic>
</sld:PointSymbolizer>
</sld:Rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the value of rotation is null using a [function](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/filter/function_reference.html):
First you need an `if_then_else` function to select the outputs based on the `isNull` function's result. If the property is `null` it returns `true` and the `if_then_else` returns the first argument (the literal), if it is not null then it returns false and the second argument of the if is used (the sub).

```
<sld:Rotation>
   <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
      <ogc:Function name="isNull">
         <ogc:PropertyName>Angle</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
   <ogc:Literal>180</ogc:Literal>
   <ogc:Sub>
      <ogc:Literal>360.0</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:PropertyName>Angle</ogc:PropertyName>
   </ogc:Sub>
   </ogc:Function>
</sld:Rotation>
```